# Using plm to account for non-individual fixed-effects in R

Tags: r, regression, panel-data

I can't figure out how to (or even whether it is possible) to use the [plm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/index.html) package in R to run a regression including fixed-effects that do not correspond to the individual observation unit. For instance, I have observations on firms' outcomes, but I need to include sector-specific dummy variables. Of course I would have to "demean" these out (because there are so many of them). Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to demean out more than one category variable. You simple demean out one, then another, then a third. Then the first isn't demeaned anymore, but you do it all over again, and continue until it's all fine. The procedure is described in a forthcoming article here: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.csda.2013.03.024 and implemented in the 'lfe' package.

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways to do this.

First, you can (I think) do it with `plm` if you don't need fixed effects for time.  In that case, pass the argument `index = c('ID', 'sector')` to `plm`, where `ID` is the ID variable for individuals and `sector` is the ID variable for sectors.  See the [plm vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/plm.pdf) for more on the `index` argument to `plm`.

If you're not wed to `plm`, just try the `lfe` package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lfe/index.html/.  The title of the package is "Linear Group Fixed Effects"; it was made for exactly the problem that you have.